# Can't add total price with respect to price and quantity

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to get the total amount with respect to the price and quantity but the total that I am getting is the double. Here is what I am using:

```
foreach ($request->product_id as $product_id){
   foreach ($request->quantity as $quantity){
       $product = Product::find($product_id);
       if($product->discount_price == null){
           $total =+ $product->selling_price * $quantity;
       }
       else{
           $total =+ $product->discount_price * $quantity;
       }
       array_push($total_price, $total);
   }
}
return array_sum($total_price);
```

Here **$request->product_id** and **$request->quantity** are array which I am returning from frontend. Because user can select multiple products and their respective quantity

If I remove **array_sum** in return statement than I see multiple repetition of the total amount (shown in the image) ...Don't know how to solve this issue

[image]

Comment: Sorry just for clarification are you trying to add all of the values together?

Comment: From your code it looks like for each product you are looping all quantities from req, I guess you only need 1 quantity per product

Comment: Can you show us your request model data

Comment: I would try and format it where the quantity is appended to the product before starting the loop. Is it an ajax form or regular form?   The nested foreach loops are causing a problem because on each product loop its looping through all quantities submitted to the post.

Comment: would array_combine ( $request->product_id , $request->quantity )  line up your array to use foreach with key index?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  foreach ($request->product_id as $key=>$product_id){
      $product = Product::find($product_id);
         if($product->discount_price == null){
             $total =+ $product->selling_price * $request->quantity[$key];
          }
          else{
              $total =+ $product->discount_price * $request->quantity[$key];
          }
       array_push($total_price, $total);
      }
    return array_sum($total_price);
```